# "The fact that there is no evidence for them counts for nothing" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Excerpted from [futuresymphony.org](http://www.futuresymphony.org/why-musicians-need-philosophy/):

> > All those assumptions involve an arbitrary intrusion of abstract thought into a realm of empirical knowledge, thereby upsetting wisdom that had been slowly acquired over centuries, and which was not in any sense the product of a single brain. **The fact that there is no evidence for them counts for nothing**, since they are philosophical, part of an a priori attempt to found an alternative to the existing music. For Adorno they promised the renewal of music, the break with a tradition that had become banal and cliché-ridden, and the hope of a fresh start in the face of cultural decline. Those thoughts were wound in to a philosophy that combined Frankfurt-school Marxism, the denunciation of popular culture, and a high-brow adulation of all that was recondite, unpredictable and difficult to follow. Adorno had the gift – the very same gift that Schoenberg had – of masking his idiosyncratic views as necessary truths, and clothing unsubstantiated speculations in the garments of priestly authority. He was the advocate of an intimidating orthodoxy. And yet the actual arguments, both in Adorno’s book and in Schoenberg’s original articles, are self-serving rhetoric, which assume what they set out to prove.

The bolded sentence is odd to me, since the whole paragraph is abasing those assumptions made by  Adorno and Schoenberg, I assume this sentence is not defending them.

But it sounds like "though there is no evidence of their assumptions, they don't need it at all in the first place, because they are philosophy, so they are not that useless" to me.

This make the tone inconsistent, with the whole paragraph reprehending but one sentence defending, do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I agree with Peter below, and I think you're more or less correct about the sentence (though I wouldn't go so far as to say "so they are not that useless"). FWIW, I don't think that the rest of the paragraph is recalling abasing the two (though it could be; it seems to me that the paragraph just lays the background for the next, which I haven't read).

Answer (score 3):

The paragraph is about how new ideas

> an arbitrary intrusion of abstract thought

can change the aesthetic of music which is

> wisdom that had been slowly acquired over centuries

The fact that

> The fact that there is no evidence for **them** counts for nothing

the **them** refers to those *avant garde* ideas and reasons which are not based (nor can they be based) on **historical precedence**, and that the lack of evidence is not reason to dismiss the new ideas.

To get around this lack of **historical evidence**, the author points out that both Adorno and Schoenberg use the **ploy** of wrapping their

> **idiosyncratic views**...and...**unsubstantiated speculations**

in

> **garments of priestly authority**

The author goes on to say that the arguments put forth are

> a high-brow adulation of all that was recondite, unpredictable and difficult to follow...
>   of an intimidating orthodoxy...
>   self-serving rhetoric, which assume what they set out to prove

The original sentence, in part, defends these techniques, possibly as a **necessary evil** for change to occur.  In other words

> [If you can't convince them, confuse them](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/12/02/confuse-them/)

or the more colloquial

> If you can't **dazzle** them with brilliance, **baffle** them with...[here](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/340982-if-you-can-t-dazzle-them-with-brilliance-baffle-them-with)

More on Schoenberg's Twelve Tone Technique can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-tone_technique) of which Adorno was a fan

Comment: I think if you aren't comfortable writing out the entire saying, you could substitute ["If you can't convince them, confuse them"](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/12/02/confuse-them/). I'm not sure a learner would be able to fill in the blank there.

Comment: @ColleenV +1 Thanks for the quote, didn't know attributable to Truman, have added it to my answer.

Comment: @Peter After rethinking the article, I think it's a bit over analysis to called it "necessary evil", I think it's more of the tone "Though they are not good philosophical concepts, they at least use philosophy trying to make music better, and it's the right attempt but should be done better, like adding some  empirical knowledge", what do you think?

Comment: I don't think the author is passing judgement on whether the philosophy is good or bad only that the **new** is based on a **philosophy** (read: aesthetic), which was (and still is) necessarily for guidance since there was **no precedent** for what they were doing and where they were going,  they had to **dead reckon** where they were going.  I think the tone the author uses when describing the techniques Adorno and Schoenberg used to promote their ideas was not favourable, yet he respects the changes that had occurred. That's why my interpretation is of **a necessary evil**, means to an end.

Comment: If you ever listened to Schoenberg, you'd understand it was **a necessary evil** on the path to Rock and Roll...